# Add column to existing table on laravel project assistance

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add a column to an existing table(mysql) on my laravel project but I have a few questions

I run the command php artisan make:migration add_time_to_customers --table=customers
This in turns obviously creates my new migration template

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
```

But I have a few databases on this instance so I am concerned about this new migration applying to the correct database and table?
I have checked out a previous column add migration and I see a reference to the actual db it needs to alter?

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('customer_db')->table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('lists');
        });
    }
```

1. Should I run my make:migration command in a different way to ensure it alters the correct table in the correct database?
2. All of the migrations pertaining to this table is also located under a sub folder for ex. migrations/customers so I want to ensure it creates the migration template in the sub folder as well
3. When I run php artisan migrate - will this not try run existing migrations again? I don't want to break my production system or loose any info
4. Can I specifically choose which migration to run and whether it is the up or down function?

Comment: `php artisan migrate` will migrate that file, which is not exist on your `migration` table, there is a `migration` table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

1- Should I run my make:migration command in a different way to ensure it alters the correct table in the correct database?

> Ans: php artisan migrate --database=**customer_db** // you need to
> add it to your database.php config file

2- All of the migrations pertaining to this table is also located under a sub folder for ex. migrations/customers so I want to ensure it creates the migration template in the sub folder as well

> ANS:php artisan make:migration create_users_table
> --path=/app/database/migrations/customers

3- When I run php artisan migrate - will this not try run existing migrations again? I don't want to break my production system or loose any info

> ANS: php artisan migrate only run not migrated files and also you can
> specify the files or paths you want to migrate

4- Can I specifically choose which migration to run and whether it is the up or down function?

> ANS: Yea, php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
> sometime this doesn't work, so you can put the needed migration in a
> sub folder and run it with path to your sub folder. About the down and
> up function  php artisan migrate always runs the up function. php
> artisan migrate:rollback always runs the down function.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. When running php artisan migrate I get an error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Server is hosted and I am trying to execute this from my local machine(VS Code connecting to Bitbucket repo). Should I execute this on the terminal on the instance itself?

Comment: Make sure your php server is running if it's apache or anything else,
and also make sure that your msql server is up and running

Comment: But this instance is not running on my local pc. Its hosted at an ISP. Should I not SSH directly into the instance and then run php artisan migrate?

Comment: It doesn't matter where it's running, you need to make sure that your Apache server or web server is up and running.

Comment: It tries to connect to localhost: mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306
Which obviously wont route from my machine to the actual instance hence the reason asking if I should run this command directly on the instance

Comment: what's the .env file on the instance?

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=pw1234

Comment: and you already have a db on the same machine with these values?